# PHP Code - Truncating not working

Tags: php

The following is snipped down HTML code I'm running on my internal webserver. I can't work out how to get the PHP truncating of the text returned from the DB to work properly:

#### EDIT: This is what I see (would like 25 characters and then ellipses)

[image]

```
<html>
<head><title>My Title</title>

<?php
    function truncate($text, $chars = 25) 
    {
        $text = $text." ";
        $text = substr($text,0,$chars);
        $text = substr($text,0,strrpos($text,' '));
        $text = $text."...";
        return $text;
    }
?>
        
</head>
<body>
<div id="mydiv">
    <table class="myTable">
        <tr>
            <td>Col 1</td>
        </tr>
        <?php
        $counter = 0;
        while ($counter < $numRows)
        {
            $f3=mysql_result($result,$counter,"url");
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="masker">
                    <a href="<?php echo $f3; ?>" target="_blank"><?php echo truncate($f3); ?></a>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <?php
            counter++;
        ?>
    </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Remove the `echo` from inside the `truncate()`.  Should just be `echo truncate($f3);`

Comment: I have done but it just produces "..." when I'm after 25 characters and then an ellipses.

Comment: `counter++` is outside of `while`. I think closing `}` should be after `counter++` not before `<tr>`.

Comment: @furas: yes you are right. I added that by mistake when posting here. Have updated the code.

Comment: I tested your `truncate()` function and it works correctly.

Comment: You still have `truncate(echo $f3)`

Comment: If all you get back is the ellipsis, then you had better verify that `$f3` contains the value you expect it to in the first place...

Answer (score 3):

`echo truncate(echo $f3);` should be `echo truncate($f3);`

Answer (score 1):

Rather than truncating the string, try CSS:

```
.someClass {
    display:inline-block;
    max-width:150px;
    white-space:nowrap;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
}
```

HTML:

```
<a href="..." target="_blank" class="someClass"><?=$f3?></a>
```

That being said, if your `$f3` is a URL, it shouldn't have any spaces so you shouldn't be able to trim it with your function anyway...

Comment: The CSS doesn't seem to work for me (appended to my CSS file). "That being said, if your $f3 is a URL, it shouldn't have any spaces so you shouldn't be able to trim it with your function anyway...", I didn't see this I pinched the code from another answer here on SO (I'm not a coder!). So I guess that's why I wasn't able to display 25 characters before the ellipses yes? Because the function couldn't find a space to chop off? What would you suggest?

Comment: `substr` by itself should work.

Comment: Found a similar Q&A over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7348103/short-text-php Thanks for your inputs.

Answer (score 0):

```
function shorter($input, $length)
{
    //no need to trim, already shorter than trim length
    if (strlen($input) <= $length) {
        return $input;
    }

    //find last space within length
    $last_space = strrpos(substr($input, 0, $length), ' ');
    if(!$last_space) $last_space = $length;
    $trimmed_text = substr($input, 0, $last_space);

    //add ellipses (...)
    $trimmed_text .= '...';

    return $trimmed_text;
}
?>
```