# PHP - a more compact function for this process?

Tags: php, function, summary

(PHP) Could be this function made more compact? I use this function for writing summary of posts on homepage. It finds first space after the limit length of text because to avoid the divsion of words for ex. My notebook is fine -> summary: My notebook.. its not should be My note...

```
function summary($posttext){
$limit = 60;

$spacepos = @strpos($posttext," ",$limit); //error handle for the texts shorter then 60 ch

while (!$spacepos){
$limit -= 10; //if text length shorter then 60 ch decrease the limit
$spacepos = @strpos($postext," ",$limit);
}

$posttext = substr($posttext,0,$spacepos)."..";

return $posttext;
}
```

Comment: Compact or not: consider the difference between strops() returning a Boolean `false` (not found) and integer `0` (found at position 0)

Comment: You really shouldn’t be using the error suppression character (`@`). It’s bad practice and makes debugging harder for yourself.

Comment: Couldn't the op just wrap it with TRIM? He's checking for a space, pretty rare that there needs to be a space as the first character of a string. In fact, if they are cleaned up on the way into the DB, what you said doesn't make much sense. Unless I'm misunderstanding.

Comment: It's not checking for a space in the __first__ character of a string; it's checking for a space in the middle (60th character initially) of a string.... that's a lot more likely than a space in the first character.... regardless of how the OP resolves the check (testing against Boolean `false` is the appropriate answer), it's a potential problem they need to be aware of

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My try to breaking without split words

```
function summary($posttext, $limit = 60){
    if( strlen( $posttext ) < $limit ) {
        return $posttext;
    }
    $offset = 0;
    $split = explode(" ", $posttext);
    for($x = 0; $x <= count($split); $x++){
        $word = $split[$x];
        $offset += strlen( $word );
        if( ($offset + ($x + 1)) >= $limit ) {
            return substr($posttext, 0, $offset + $x) . '...';
        }
    }
    return $posttext;
}
```

Comment: this url has a few good ideas. It doesn't really seem like there's a built in function for this one, if that was what you were looking for. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7348103/short-text-php

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will split on the last full word without breaking the word.

```
function limit_text($text, $len) {
        if (strlen($text) < $len) {
            return $text;
        }
        $text_words = explode(' ', $text);
        $out = null;


        foreach ($text_words as $word) {
            if ((strlen($word) > $len) && $out == null) {

                return substr($word, 0, $len) . "...";
            }
            if ((strlen($out) + strlen($word)) > $len) {
                return $out . "...";
            }
            $out.=" " . $word;
        }
        return $out;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your helps.I corrected my codes according to your suggestions.And the final version is this:

```
function summary($posttext){
$limit = 60;

if (strlen($posttext)<$limit){

$posttext .= "..";  

}else {
$spacepos = strpos($posttext," ",$limit);   
$posttext = substr($posttext,0,$spacepos)."..";
}
return $posttext;   
}
```